# marquee horizontal doesn't show all items

Tags: css, vue.js

I want to use a marquee style for my items:

This is my style:

```
@keyframes marquee-horizontal-alt {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}
#main .slider__doctors {
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #08B89D;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 200;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
#main .slider__doctors ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  will-change: transform;
  animation: marquee-horizontal-alt 120s linear infinite;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
#main .slider__doctors ul li {
  margin-right: 2vw;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#main .slider__doctors__name {
  font-size: calc(1.3125rem + 0.75vw);
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

but when my page is loaded, it doesn't show all items.
for example I have 57 items. but the first items about 20 items not visible. my page when loaded It starts to be displayed from item 21.

I'm using vuejs:

```
<template lang="pug">
.slider.slider__doctors
    ul(style="flex")
      li(v-for="doctor in doctors")
        span.slider__doctors__name {{ doctor.full_name }}
        span.slider__doctors__expert  ({{ doctor.expert_type }} {{ doctor.expert }})

</template>
```

[image]